# Dynamically creating a TreeViewin HTML with indent lines in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

i'm quite new to HTML, and am trying to create a professional looking TreeView.
I can not use the in built TreeView in ASP.NET as i need to point the target of the selection to another frame (I have tried, and this doesn't seem possible). 
My TreeView is built up as follows:

Folder1

- ChildOne
- ChildTwo
- ChildThree

Folder2

- ChildOne
- ChildTwo
- ChildThree

I have the collapsing of the folders working, but would like to know how to format this TreeView so it has dotted lines down to the child nodes (as most TreeViews tend to have).

How would i go about this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is to point the target of the selection to another frame, then you just need to use the `Target` propery,

The [TreeView.Target Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.target.aspx) gets or sets the target window or frame in which to display the Web page content associated with a node.

Moreover, Target value must begin with a letter in the range of A through Z (case-insensitive), except for certain special values that begin with an underscore, as shown below :

- **_blank** : Renders the content in a new window without frames.
- **_parent** :  Renders the content in the immediate frameset parent.
- **_search** : Renders the content in the search pane.
- **_self** : Renders the content in the frame with focus.
- **_top** : Renders the content in the full window without frames.

The default value is an empty string (""), which targets the window or frame with focus.